# C# MSGraph SDK and ipNamedLocation

Tags: c#, ip-address, microsoft-graph-api

I've been working on C# app to amend the ipaddress/s of a Named Location in conditional access in  AAD.

I can authenticate and return the request collection. For whatever reason I cant access the `isTrusted` property or the `ipRanges` odata.

I can see the properties and the vales when I run through in debug, but cant output them.

I think its something to do with the list type, I'm using `Microsoft.Graph.NamedLocation`, there is `Microsoft.Graph.IpNamedLocation` type available but it can be converted from `Microsoft.Graph.NamedLocation`, which the api call makes.

The image shows what's available during runtime.

[image: method code image]

Code Below:

```
private static async Task GetnamedLocations(IConfidentialClientApplication app, string[] scopes)
{
    GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient = GetAuthenticatedGraphClient(app, scopes);

    var namedlocationsList = new List<Microsoft.Graph.NamedLocation>();
        
    var namedLocations = await graphServiceClient.Identity.ConditionalAccess.NamedLocations
         .Request()
         .Filter("isof('microsoft.graph.ipNamedLocation')")
         .GetAsync();

       // var ipNamedLocations = new List<Microsoft.Graph.IpNamedLocation>();

       

    namedlocationsList.AddRange(namedLocations.CurrentPage);

    foreach (var namedLocation in namedlocationsList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(namedLocation.Id + namedLocation.DisplayName + namedLocation.ODataType + namedLocation);

        if (namedLocation.ODataType == "#microsoft.graph.ipNamedLocation")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Write out all the properties");
        }
          
    }

      
    Console.WriteLine(($"Named location: {namedLocations}"));
}
```

Any pointers gratefully received, I'm not a C# developer so be gentle :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cast `namedLocation` to `IpNamedLocation` type.

```
foreach (var namedLocation in namedlocationsList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(namedLocation.Id + namedLocation.DisplayName + namedLocation.ODataType + namedLocation);

    if (namedLocation is IpNamedLocation ipNamedLocation)
    {
        var isTrusted = ipNamedLocation.IsTrusted;
        var ipRanges = ipNamedLocation.IpRanges;
        if (ipRanges is IEnumerable<IPv4CidrRange> ipv4cidrRanges)
        {
            foreach(var ipv4cidrRange in ipv4cidrRanges)
            {
                 Console.WriteLine($"{ipv4cidrRange.CidrAddress}");
            }
         }

        Console.WriteLine("Write out all the properties");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that's solved that issue. I tried using the same technique for the ipRanges object and casting it to IPv4CidrRange but that does not work, any ideas?
               
if (namedLocation is IpNamedLocation ipNamedLocation)
   {
     var isTrusted = ipNamedLocation.IsTrusted;
     var ipRanges = ipNamedLocation.IpRanges;

         if (ipRanges is IPv4CidrRange ipv4cidrRange)
            {
              Console.WriteLine($"ipv4cidrRange.CidrAddress");
            }
    }

Comment: @Computastar It can work because IpRanges is collection of IPv4CidrRange. Check update answer.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the updated answer to work, it still didn't evaluate the if statement to true, after a bit of googling and trying different options, the following returns the IP address, not sure if its the right way to go about it but it works.

```
                var ipv4CidrRanges = ipRanges.Cast<IPv4CidrRange>().ToList();
                                     
                foreach (var ipv4CidrRange in ipv4CidrRanges)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ipv4CidrRange.CidrAddress);
                }
```

Many thanks to user2250152 who solved the first conundrum for me.